# Cannot dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I had Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop, then I determined to install Windows 7 and keep both of 
them on my machine (dual boot), then I installed Window 7.

And then Windows 7 was running, but Ubuntu didn't appear in the grub menu.

I then ran Ubuntu from a live usb disk and edited GRUB to make Ubuntu boot:

```
sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /mnt
sudo rm -rf /boot
sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot
```

Now Ubuntu 11.10 is booting automatically when the laptop start, but Windows 7 doesn't appear at all in the grub (there is no grub menu at all).

Now I want to let Windows 7 appear in the grub menu to let me choose (Ubuntu + Windows 7). I've read these commands but it doesn't work with me:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

- A large text file will open and at the bottom leave a line and add this:
- (Just a blank text file opened with me -not a large one- i don't know why)

  ```
  title windows 7 beta (Loader)
  root (hd0,1)
  savedefault
  makeactive
  chainloader +1
  ```

Do not type this line but if that does not work on re-boot try `hd0,0` or `hd0,2` and so on until it works.

Comment: The commands don't work because that's for an old version of GRUB. Could you please include the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in your answer?

Comment: that's right RobinJ.. when i updated the grub  it worked well.. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `sudo update-grub` from a terminal in Ubuntu. That should add Windows to the GRUB menu.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help .. i does work with me now..i can switch windows7 and ubuntu 11.10..thanks again

Comment: @Salahuddin I see your new on AskUbuntu. When an answer solved your problem, it's usual to click the *tick* icon on the left of the answer so that it becomes green, marking the answer as accepted. :)