# Can't boot to Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

Here's what happened:
I have 2 HDDs.

1st HDD is partitioned like this:
C - Windows 7
D* - Empty drive where I installed Ubuntu
E - Personal Files
F - Personal Files

2nd HDD is partitioned like this:
G - Personal Files

*the D partition is originally part of the C partition. I resized it
(using Easus Partition Master in Windows) and defragged it prior to
installing Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu by booting to the Ubuntu Secure Remix CD, and chose
the D partition to install Ubuntu. I did not create a swap drive, and
I mounted the / to the D partition. I didnt know where to mount the
others, so I just thought by mounting the / to D, it would be okay.

After the long installation, upon rebooting, I can't access Windows
AND Ubuntu. I get an infinite bootloop and eventually the choices to
boot to Safe Modes, Last Known Good Configuration and Start Windows
normally. After failing in all of them, I placed the CD back and ran
the Boot Repair. I chose the MBR 1st, it didn't work. I then chose the
GRUB 2nd and now I was able to boot to the Ubuntu I installed, but not
to my Windows 7! I'm using my newly installed Ubuntu while writing
this.

I hope you can help me. I did the best I could!

Here's the link to the boot repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/919354/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you remember which drive did you choose to install grub? These option are in below of gparted window (where you set that mount point). I guess it was wrong and also which disk is set to boot first? Check BIOS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78527/cannot-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu)

Comment: Take a look at lines around 367. Unless that's a flashdrive, having "facebook" in the boot sector is a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

from bootlog, it seems your 1st boot device is second hard disk. Though windows is in Hard disk 1 (sda) the bootloader for windows is located in Hard disk 2 (sdb2).

I would suggest (safest way)

- Remove / temporary disable 2nd hard disk with personal files.
- Use windows 7 disk to restore windows 7. Use /fixboot and /fixmbr option if automatic start up repair failed. (google a bit)
- Install ubuntu. Make sure grub is installing in `sda1` .
- Reboot to see if both are working properly.
- Reconnect 2nd Hard disk, open bios. Change boot order to boot from hard disk 1.

*Optional:*

- Boot in windows, open disk management utility.("diskmgmt.msc"). Delete 200mb parition in 2nd hard disk and extend partition labeled as "Personal file"